# How to have a 'click' event on an element inserted by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, haml

I would like to toggle an on | off element so that it bolds the currently selected option and provides a link to the other option.  A fairly common pattern.  I got the row shading itself working, however presenting the links (or text) to turn it on and off are proving troublesome.

When 'on' is clicked, row shading should turn on [works] and then the "on" link should change to (bold) text and 'off" should be a link to reverse this [does not work].

Similarly when 'off' is clicked, row shading should turn off [works] and the "off" link should change to be (bold) text [works] and the "on" text should change to be a link that can turn it on again when clicked [does not work].

the link is clicked the reverse should happen and the link should become text and the text become a link.
Most of that happens but I end up with a link that doesn't do anything in the ui or seem to show me any console errors.

I started with the following HAML (HTML is also shown below)

```
%span.spaced
  Group Shading:
  %span#group_shading_toggle
    - if session[:group_shading] == 'true'
      %b  
        On
      %a{href: '#', id: 'row_colors_off'}
        Off
    - else
      %a{href: '#', id: 'row_colors_on'}
        On
      %b  
        Off
```

and I have javascript of:

```
$(function()
{
    $("a#row_colors_on").click(function()
    {
        $(".row_color_group_1").addClass("color_group_1");
        $(".row_color_group_2").addClass("color_group_2");
        $(".row_color_group_3").addClass("color_group_3");
        // Replace the "on" toggle link with plain "on" and the group shading "off" *text* with link to off
        $("#group_shading_toggle").html("On <a href='#' id='row_colors_off'>Off</a>");
        $.get('/set_group_shading?show=true').defaultPrevented;
     });
});

$(function()
{
    $("a#row_colors_off").click(function()
    {
       $(".row_color_group_1").removeClass("color_group_1");
       $(".row_color_group_2").removeClass("color_group_2");
       $(".row_color_group_3").removeClass("color_group_3");
       // Replace the "off" toggle link with a "off" text and the group shading "on" link with *text* "on"
       $("#group_shading_toggle").html("<a href='#' id='row_colors_on'>On</a> off");
       $.get('/set_group_shading?show=false');
    });
});
```

The html 'before' that is generatd is:

```
<span class="spaced">


                      Group Shading:
                    …

    <span id="group_shading_toggle">
        <a id="row_colors_on" href="#">


                                  On


        </a>
        Off
    </span>

</span>
```

and the html 'after' that is generated after the click is:

```
<span class="spaced">


                      Group Shading:
                    …

    <span id="group_shading_toggle">

        On 

        <a id="row_colors_off" href="#">Off</a>
    </span>

</span>
```

However that off dynamically generated "off" link

doesn't work, even though it seems the same as

```
<a id="row_colors_off" href="#">


                          Off


</a>
```

which if rendered initially for that state, *does* work.

Why doesn't displaying the link from the js not work?

I've provided more code than usual to help others attempting similar toggle buttons and looking for a variety of solutions.

Comment: Added the off text for the link afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click() binding will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have create a "delegated" binding by using on()

Give that a try.